# Conditions for a bivariate function to be bounded?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, upper-lower-bounds

It is known that a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}$ exist and are finite is bounded. See, e.g., 
[Prove that a continuous real function with finite limits is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118478/prove-that-a-continuous-real-function-with-finite-limits-is-bounded?rq=1)

My question: Is there some kind of condition on limits for bivariate functions? I.e., are there conditions for $\lim_{x,y}$, $\lim_x$ and $\lim_y$ such that a continuous $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R},(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$ is bounded $(|f(x,y)|\le M$ for an $M$)?

Comment: "If the limit $\lim_{\|(x,y)\|\to\infty}f(x,y)$ exists, and $f$ is continuous, then the function is bounded." admits the same proof.

Comment: **Hint:** With $y=y_0\in\Bbb R$ fixed, consider $\Phi(x)=f(x,y_0)$ which is continuous due to continuity of $f$. Analogously consider $\varphi(y)=f(x_0,y)$ for some $x=x_0\in\Bbb R$ fixed. You can now apply the conditions for the 1D case on $\Phi$ and $\varphi$ to analyze the boundedness of $f$